# jQuery load selected tab when page refreshed

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, tabs

[image]

I have a button for adding new user in the tab "User Setup" but when i click it the page redirects back to the tab "Retail Site Setup." (**because of the query string "?tab=AdditionalProducts"**).

When i select "User Setup" tab again, it shows the right form for adding new user so the user setup tab is opening correctly but due to the query string its messing around.

My sample code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $('#tabs').click('tabsselect', function (event, ui) {
     document.getElementById('hdnCurIndex').value = $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active');
    });  

    if (document.getElementById('hdnCurIndex').value != -1) {
    $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", document.getElementById('hdnCurIndex').value);                 
    }            
  });
```

So please tell how to show the "User Setup" tab again when Add new user button clicked and page refreshed.

hdnCurIndex value is returning 3 which is the index of "User Setup" tab. The main problem is the Query String.When the page loads it just redirected to the "?tab=additionalProducts", 
How can i change it to "?tab=useraccess" or completely remove it.

PS: This query string(?tab=additionalProducts) is adding if someone directly want to go to a perticular tab from the Menu control(Addminitration).

Answer (score 0):

please use selected in place of active in below line.

```
if (document.getElementById('hdnCurIndex').value != -1) {
    $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected ", document.getElementById('hdnCurIndex').value);                 
    }
```

Comment: But i guess for jquery-1.9.1.js selected changed into active.

Comment: then please check that your hdnCurIndex is returning proper value.

Comment: yes its returning 3 which is the index of "User Setup" tab. The main problem is the Query String.When the page loads it just redirected to the "?tab=additionalProducts", How can i change it to "?tab=useraccess" or completely remove it.